# How to reuse and plot more than once the same plot

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

Using matplotlib, on Jupyter books, I want to make a figure with some plots, show it, add more plots, and show it again (old and new plots)

instead, it shows me only new plots on the new second image

This is the code I have:

```
import numpy as np
%matplotlib inline  
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

a=np.random.rand(10,)
b=np.random.rand(10,)

fig1 = plt.figure(1)
plt.plot(a,'b')
#plt.draw();
plt.show();

plt.figure(1)
plt.plot(b,'g--')
plt.show();
```

left is what I have, right is what I want :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pcGH0.png)

---

The question upside has been reduced to the most simplistic form, therefore I may have not explain that I do not want to having to recreate the figure each time (as it has about 15 lines to configure as I desire)

This is an example of code I DO NOT want:

```
import numpy as np
%matplotlib inline  
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

a=np.random.rand(10,)
b=np.random.rand(10,)
c=np.random.rand(10,)

plt.plot(a, 'b')
plt.grid(True)

dig, ax = plt.subplots(1)
ax.plot(a,'b')
ax.plot(b,'g--')

dig, bx = plt.subplots(1)
bx.plot(a,'b')
bx.plot(b,'g--')
bx.plot(c,'r.')

plt.show()
```

this is a sort of pseudocode I would expect:

```
a=np.random.rand(10,)
b=np.random.rand(10,)
c=np.random.rand(10,)

my_plot = plt.figure()
my_plot.grid(True)

my_plot.addplot(a,'b')
my_plot.show()

my_plot.addplot(a,'g--')
my_plot.show()

my_plot.addplot(a,'r.')
my_plot.show()
```

(I know, this is not phyton/matplotlib, but I am sure something elegant like this should be possible)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import numpy as np
%matplotlib inline  
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

a=np.random.rand(10,)
b=np.random.rand(10,)
c=np.random.rand(10,)
d=np.random.rand(10,)

p = [a,b,c,d]
colors = ['r','g','b', 'g--']
for i in range(len(p)):
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(1)
    for j in range(i + 1):
        ax.plot(p[j], colors[j])
```

[image: plot]

Comment: soory, but this is what I try to avoid, having to re-draw all the plots for every time I need the plot

Comment: I have added more examples in the original cuestion

Comment: sorry, where is the original drawing??

Comment: the real thing, I have like 15 images, and each one is by adding a new line/couple of lines to the previous one

Comment: @widot check the updated answer, I hope that is what you are looking for.

Comment: not really what I was looking for, but a very elegant way to achieve the same thing, Interesting, thanks a lot !!